# jQuery in Wordpress not working as expected in Chrome

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've been having this weird issue with jQuery which came with Wordpress 3.2.1. I'm developing a WordPress plugin. I'm using Chrome to do my debugging. I would normally turn on the developer tools to try out some jQuery function before putting them into the code. But for this particular combination, I have had problem with namely the ID selector and various HTML Object function.

```
jQuery('#id_of_html_element') //This will just return [] in the console

//If I put this in the plugin, it will run and show [object Object]
alert(jQuery('#id_of_html_element'));


//The following shows "null" but in fact I have html inside
alert(jQuery('#id_of_html_element').html());

//And this works as expected in the console
document.getElementById('id_of_html_element').innerHTML
```

I've tried disabling all extension on my Chrome, but the problem remains. On another page (e.g. Stackoverflow.com), jQuery works as expected in the console.

EDIT: Class selector does works properly in the console but `html()` still returns null

EDIT: Sorry, it was my mistake. I had a "-" in the id, which causes the problem. After replacing it with underscore, it works already. I notice it when it works on other wordpress plugin, but not mine.

Comment: you keep saying Chrome.  Does it work in Firefox? I doubt it's a Chrome issue.  More likely the loading order of Wordpress.  I had a similar problem not to long ago.  Just put the <script call in your head

Comment: I only have Chrome installed at the moment. <head> is not possible, as this is a WP plugin, not theme.

Comment: ah, right, sorry about that, for kicks and giggle, have you tried putting it in your head just for testing.  Then you'll know if it's a browser issue or a wordpress loading order issue

Comment: np, I've just tried with IE9, same problem.

Comment: Is this being called after DOM ready? jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 //getting selector html() now that DOM tree has been built.
});

Comment: Yes, definitely. Also I'm doing it in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If really want to access to html code inside element ID, try my solution:

```
var v1 = $('<div>').append($("#id_of_html_element").find("*").clone()).remove().html();
alert(v1);
```

I tested that on :

```
<div id="id_of_html_element">
        <a href="#">Text</a>
        <br/><a href="#">Another Text</a>
</div>
```

and the alert result was :

> `<a href="#">Text</a><br><a href="#">Another Text</a>`

I tested that on FF, Chrome and that thing called IE, and everything seemed working well !

Don't ask me about white-spaces where they gone, its your problem now :P :P :P

Hopefully that helpful for you :)

Comment: The sample code I have would normally works, it just fail on my plugin page inside wordpress

Comment: Since no one else answered, and I've found out the problem, I'll just mark yours as answer